# Summerize Time in area

Tags: sql, sql-server

i just have huge data of technitions that can be OnSite or OnTheWay , 
i want to summerize in witch site they been and for how long. 
Example:

```
id        UpdateTime            UserName    SiteID
488565  2019-02-18 19:07:24.000 stephen      null
488388  2019-02-18 17:34:52.000 stephen      297
488558  2019-02-18 18:06:48.000 stephen      297
488565  2019-02-18 18:07:24.000 stephen      297
488565  2019-02-18 14:07:24.000 stephen      null
483170  2019-02-18 13:53:14.000 stephen      299
488565  2019-02-18 11:07:24.000 stephen      null
483170  2019-02-18 10:53:14.000 stephen      297
```

the technition was in 297 twice this day , i want to get this result  per tech (End Time is the when i got Null or Diffrent SiteID):

```
UserName    InComeTime                 TimeInSite(min)     SiteID
stephen      2019-02-18 10:53:14.000     14                 297
stephen      2019-02-18 13:53:14.000     14                 299
stephen      2019-02-18 17:34:52.000     153                 297
```

thanks, 
eyal

Comment: Why two rows for siteID 297 and how do you identify the end time? Maybe you could add your own attempt at solving this?

Comment: I assume that when siteID is null that they have left the previous site?

Comment: Also, please can you tag your DBMS?

Comment: yes, when it's null they left the site, and my dbms is MSsql

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because no reputation :( ?!? so I'll post as answer although some questions remain. In principle you can work along the lines of joining null-value site records onto not-null site records. If you can't warrant that null-value siteIds mean 'exit' and not-null siteIds mean entry then there is no 'starting point' and you'd need to do a table scan. If you *can* warrant it (or deal with exceptions separately) then the query could take on the following form:

```
select t1.UserName, 
    t1.UpdateTime as EntryTime, 
    t2.UpdateTime as ExitTime, 
    datediff(MI, t1.UpdateTime, t2.UpdateTime) as TimeInSite, 
    t1.SiteId
from TimeTable t1
join TimeTable t2 on t2.id in 
    (select id from TimeTable 
        where 
            -- want the same user
            UserName = t1.UserName
            -- site id null/different means 'exited site'
            and (siteId is null)  
            -- now get the entry with the minium update time that is greater than the entry time
            and UpdateTime = (select min(UpdateTime) from TimeTable where UpdateTime > t1.UpdateTime
        )
    )
where t1.SiteId is not null
order by EntryTime
```

This does not take into account that you can have multiple 'not-null' siteIds for the same visit (i.e. the three 297s). Ideally this should be avoided. If you can't then you could first collate those entries into a temp table to only pick the the first entry time.

The above query outputs the following (SQL server, note that I have added entry and exit time for clarity). It is not 100% what you wanted because of the multiple 297s, but maybe it gets you started. Out of time now, maybe someone else can provide a 100% solution. Good luck!

```
UserName     EntryTime               ExitTime                TimeInSite  SiteId
------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
stephen      2019-02-18 10:53:14.000 2019-02-18 11:07:24.000 14          297
stephen      2019-02-18 13:53:14.000 2019-02-18 14:07:24.000 14          299
stephen      2019-02-18 18:07:24.000 2019-02-18 19:07:24.000 60          297
```

Comment: `Can't comment because no reputation :( ?!?` that's because people should understand how SO works and the difference between a Q&A site and a discussion forum. That's why comments are so limited, They can be deleted at any moment too. This answer would never fit in a comment .50 rep can be gained quite easily

Comment: It made me answer based on some assumptions rather than being able to ask some clarifying questions first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions.  You want to assign groups to the rows and then aggregate.  How is the grouping defined?

In this case, you want to include the next `NULL` value in the group.  So, a definition that works for you is the number of `NULL` values accumulated in reverse order.  That is:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when siteId is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userName order by updatetime desc) as grp
from t;
```

Then you can aggregate to get what you want:

```
select username, min(siteid) as siteid,
       min(updatetime) as incometime,
       datediff(minute, min(updatetime), max(updatetime)) as minutes
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when siteId is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userName order by updatetime desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```